# I keep getting [Linker error] undefined reference to `binarytree::~binarytree()'

Tags: c++, binary-tree, destructor

```
#ifndef BINARYTREE_H
#define BINARYTREE_H
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class binarytree
{
      private:
      struct tree
      {
             int val;
             tree *left;
             tree *right;
      };
      tree *root;
      void insert(tree *&, tree *&);
      void display(tree *) const;
      void destroy(tree *);
    public:

        binarytree()
        {root = NULL;}
        ~binarytree()
        {destroy(root);}

        void insertnode(int);
        bool search(int);
        void display() const
        { display(root); }
};

#endif // BINARYTREE_H
```

this is my .h

and this is my .cpp

```
#include "binarytree.h" // class's header file
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void binarytree :: insertnode( int num)
{
     tree *newnode;

     newnode = new tree;
     newnode->val = num;
     newnode->left = newnode->right = NULL;
     insert(root, newnode);
     }

     void binarytree :: insert(tree *&Ptr, tree *&newnode)
     {
          if(Ptr == NULL)
                 Ptr = newnode;
                 else if( newnode->val < Ptr->val)
                 insert(Ptr->left, newnode);
                 else
                 insert(Ptr->right, newnode);
                 }

void binarytree :: destroy(tree *Ptr)
{
     if(Ptr)
     {
            if(Ptr->left)
            destroy(Ptr->left);

             if(Ptr->right)
            destroy(Ptr->right);

            delete Ptr;
            }
     }
```

i assume that this is a destructor error but i cant see why. if there is a syntax error or something i will feel very silly but i have just been copying this from a book so it doesnt seem like im missing anything. any advice would help. If you need any clarification just ask!

Comment: your code compiles fine here.

Comment: only destructor is noticed?

Comment: `using namespace std;` - Don't ever put that in your header files.

Comment: Make sure you don' have a stray `binarytree.h` file somewhere else.

Comment: @user1914650 Your code compiles absolutely fine in Microsoft visual C++.What Compiler are you using and how are you compiling?

Comment: Also, you have violated the rule of three.  If I copy a `binary_tree` you have a double delete.

Comment: @EdS. maybe this class is never copied

Comment: @user191450 answer our questions

Comment: @cf16 following the rule of three is *always* a good idea - if you have one of the "three", then just have all three (even if only to `=delete` them in C++11 or using a "declare private but don't implement" workaround in C++03). It will save a lot of headaches down the road.

Comment: I'd like to second what @stardust_ said - make sure the binarytree.h that you are including is the one that you think you are including. Cheap-and-dirty way: add the line `#warning This is the file I want to include` somewhere in your header file, and look for the warning when you compile. If you are including that file (and not some other file), you'll either see the warning (if your compiler supports `#warning`) or get an error (that it doesn't). Either way you'll know.

Comment: (cont. from prev. comment) If neither of these things happens, then you're likely **not** including that file as you thought you were, but another binarytree.h file where the destructor is declared but not implemented.

Comment: @cf16: Until it is, and then... oops.  why write sloppy code with obvious and unnecessary points of failure?